# JQuery function is breaking html while appending?

Tags: jquery, append, markup, validation

If you look at my code it looks fine.

This is what I'm putting in the source:

```
<ul id="blinds1" class="window"></ul>
```

This is a rough idea of what the browser spits out after the jQuery is run:

```
<ul id="blinds1" class="window">
<li style="background-position: 0px 0px;" class="image"></li>
<li style="background-position: -40px 0px;" class="image"></li>
</ul>
```

This is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".window").addBlinds();
});

jQuery.fn.addBlinds = function() {
    if ( this.exists() ){
        return this.each(function() {
            var ul = $(this), sect = 0, size = 12, loc = 0, time = 200;

            addSection();

            function addSection() {
                if (sect < size) {
                    setTimeout(function(){  
                        var section = $("<li />")
                        .css({backgroundPosition: loc+"px 0px"})
                        .addClass("image");
                        ul.append(section);
                        section.slideDown(time, "swing");
                        loc-=40;
                        sect++;
                        addSection();
                    }, time);
                }
            };

            ul.append("<div class='clear' />");
        });
    } else { return false };
};
```

.exists() was a little plugin I created just for the sake of not confusing myself later on when I look at my code.

Oooookay!  Now to the point that has me stumped.
For some reason when I go to the markup validation I get this:

> Line 61, Column 41: end tag for "ul"
>   which is not finished

URL of page in question:  http://www.blanktree.com/about/

URL of validation page: http://validator.w3.org/

Can anyone help me out here?  What the heck is going on? hahaha

**Somewhat Resolved:**

Apparently there has to be an existing child `<li></li>` in the parent `<ul></ul>` even before the javascript is called for it to accept it as valid code.  I simply put an empty child in there to clear the error.  However....  This is more of a work around than a resolution.  This seems like an issue with the validator more than it is with my code.  Is there a better way I should be going about this?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to make an empty list (as-is) valid. You can either:

- creating a temporary empty li (as you've already discovered)
- use a placeholder div, and either append the ul to it, or replace the div with the ul, in the addBlinds plugin.

Comment: Thanks.  I've thought about all of this actually.  Ended up just placing an empty li to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a `div` tag **inside** the `ul`. You probably meant to call `after()`

```
ul.after("<div class='clear' />");
```

You could also use any developer tools such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or what not to view the html source and confirm check to see where the error might lie.

#### ADDITIONAL ANSWER

`ul` and `ol` 's are **required** to have children otherwise it's invalid. To solve this you could wrap your `ul` in a `div` and add the `ul` via javascript as well rather than inserting the ul in code by default.

Comment: beat me by a few seconds.  if i were sober you'd have beaten me :)

Comment: If I hadn't taken the time to make sure it was `after` I would have been faster :)

Comment: eh, i knew it was after but it's hard to type. you got my upvote.

Comment: Even with .after() it still gives the same markup error.  After also doesn't give the same result.  The point of a clear is to force the wrap of the parent element.  However.  I failed to realize that UL auto wraps the elements no mater if they are floating or not.  It doesn't function the same as a div.  So there is no need for the clear there at all.  However, even without that I still get the same error from the markup validator.  I already use development tools in Chrome which is somewhat similar to firebug.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be your `ul.append(...);`

append puts whatever you have passed in inside the element.

maybe you want `ul.after(...);`